# C# TraceListner not working when published to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tracelistener

The following code returns trace output just fine in Visual Studios however when I try to run the same code on IIS in an aspx page it stops working.  Is this possible and if so what am I missing?

```
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            StringBuilder traceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(traceBuilder);
            using (System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener textWriterTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(stringWriter))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(textWriterTraceListener);
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Flush();
                textWriterTraceListener.Flush();
            }

            stringWriter.Flush();
            string traceOutput = traceBuilder.ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("traceOutput - " + traceOutput);
```

Comment: How are you outputting `traceOutput`?

Comment: Hmm that's strange. I'd set a breakpoint on and step through the code to see what's going on.

Comment: When I debug it skips the Trace.WriteLine line of code.  So that explains why I'm not getting output but why is it skipping that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Had to add the following to the web.config file:

```
<system.codedom>
 <compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
            extension=".cs" 
            compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" />
 </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```